# Reading array from a text file

Tags: c++, file

I have the following text file and I have an array created using vector template class (call it x) in which I want to assign the array elements. The user inputs the value of n and based on the n value, my array created using vector template class should store the values of that array.

Eg: If user enters 5, x should store the values of elements in: legendre_roots[5].
Can someone suggest how do I read from the file so that I can store the array elements for a specific n. I can use push_back() to feed values to x but before that I need to find the array in the text file.[image]

This is the code which I tried:

```
while(fin1.getline(')') && fin2.getline(')'))
{
    fin1.getline([n]);
    fin2.getline([n]);
    fin1>>score1;
    fin2>>score2;
    x = push_back(score1);
    w = push_back(score2);
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This is not just "a text file", this is PHP code.

Comment: I converted this php into txt file

Comment: What if user enters 0 or 1?

Comment: User has to enter number between 2 and 64

Comment: And `$legendre_roots[64]` has 64 lines?

Comment: yes, legendre_roots[2] to legendre_roots[64], there are 63 such arrays

Comment: $legendre_roots[n] will have n elements

Comment: Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it. Read first char of each line (assuming `$legendre_roots` starts from beginning of the line), and see if it is `$`. If not go to the next line... until found. Then read the text following `$` into string and see if it matches the array name with required index. If not start again until found.

When found, iterate known number of times (equal to index) to read all the data into array cleaning it of tabs and punctuation along the way. Here is sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss(R"(

$legendre_roots = array();

$legendre_roots[2] = (
    0.123213213213213,
    -8.123213213213213);

$legendre_roots[3] = (
    0.123213213213213,
    8.123213213213213,
    3.1232133213);

$legendre_roots[4] = (
    0,
    3.1232144444,
    8.123213213213213,
    3.1232133213);
)");

    size_t n;
    std::cout << "Enter N from 2 to 4: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    char dollar_sign;
    std::string array_name, search_name = "legendre_roots[" + std::to_string(n) + "]", delims("-.0123456789");
    std::vector<std::string> array_elements(n);

    while (iss >> dollar_sign)
    {
        if (dollar_sign == '$' && iss >> array_name && array_name == search_name)
        {
            iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                std::string line;
                std::getline(iss, line, '\n');
                size_t start = line.find_first_of(delims), end = line.find_first_not_of(delims, start);
                array_elements[i] = line.substr(start, end - start);
            }
            break;
        }
        iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    for (auto const &element : array_elements)
        std::cout << element << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/cQyLNh

Comment: I don't want to use the text file in my prog, the text file is too big. How can I read the text file and then store values in the array?

Comment: This was just an example. You can replace istringstream with ifstream

Comment: Can u suggest online C++ compiler which allows me to use text file for input and output?

Comment: This one can write and read files: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=eee065da4d45b811 but I don't know how to pass `cin` to it, so I edited it out of the example

Comment: we need to provide the file in the command window itself? Can't I upload my text file into it?

Comment: For online compiler? Don't think so, you can make it and then read it. Look at the example I posted, it writes into file and then you have file to read from, for the sake of reading from file. Of course, as I shown you here, you can always use `stringstream` instead of `filestream`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166701/discussion-between-cool-5275-and-killzone-kid).